# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same in Java

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a prepardStatement which should perform an insert to MS Access

Below is the SQL

```
INSERT INTO DonorDetails (Title,FirstName,LastName,[IC NUMBER],[OLD IC NUMBER],Gender,DOB,COUNTRY,Race,[Address 1],[Address 2],[Address 3],[Address 4],City,State,Postcode,[TEL HSE],[TEL HP],[TEL OFF],[Fax Number],Email,Language,[Donation Amount],Frequency,Bank,MODE,[CHQ/MO/PO],[CREDIT CARD],[NAME OF CARD HOLDER],Expiry,[ISSUING BANK],[ACCOUNT NUMBER],CAMPAIGN,[SERIAL NO],[EVENT CODE],[AGENT ID],Channel,[SOURCE CODE],[SIGNUP DATE],Remarks, [Date Processed])values (?,?,?.?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

During insert I get the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.
```

This is how I execute my code which I believe the number of fields / columns is 41

```
            Connection conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
            System.out.println(sql);
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, salutation);
            pst.setString(2, txtFirstName.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtLastName.getText());
            pst.setString(4, newID);
            pst.setString(5, oldID);
            pst.setString(6, String.valueOf(cbGender.getSelectedItem()));
            pst.setString(7, dobDate);
            pst.setString(8, String.valueOf(cbNationality.getSelectedItem()));
            pst.setString(9, race);
            pst.setString(10, txtAddress.getText());
            pst.setString(11, txtAddress2.getText());
            pst.setString(12, txtAddress3.getText());
            pst.setString(13, txtAddress4.getText());
            pst.setString(14, txtCity.getText());
            pst.setString(15, String.valueOf(cbState.getSelectedItem()));
            pst.setString(16, txtPostCode.getText());
            pst.setString(17, txtHomePhone.getText());
            pst.setString(18, txtMobilePhone.getText());
            pst.setString(19, txtOfficePhone.getText());
            pst.setString(20, txtFax.getText());
            pst.setString(21, txtEmail.getText());
            pst.setString(22, txtLanguage.getText());
            pst.setInt(23, amount);
            pst.setString(24, frequency);
            pst.setString(25, bankName);
            pst.setString(26, mode);
            pst.setString(27, prependNo + txtRefNo.getText());
            pst.setString(28, cardNumber);
            pst.setString(29, cardName);
            pst.setString(30, cardExpiry);
            pst.setString(31, issuingBank);
            pst.setString(32, accountNumber);
            pst.setString(33, String.valueOf(cbCampaign.getSelectedItem()));
            pst.setString(34, lblSerialCode.getText()
                    + txtSerialNumber.getText());
            pst.setString(35, txtTeritoryCode.getText());
            pst.setString(36, txtAgentID.getText());
            pst.setString(37, String.valueOf(cbChannel.getSelectedItem()));
            pst.setString(38, "OPTIMO");
            pst.setString(39, df.format(signUpDate.getDate()));
            pst.setString(40, textField.getText());
            pst.setString(41, processedDate);
            pst.execute();
```

I am unable to find what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: You have a period (`.`) instead of a comma (`,`) between the third and fourth question mark placeholders (`?`) in the command text.

Comment: Can we mark it as closed?